Create vector layer using specific cells from a raster
I need to create a point layer from a big raster layer in QGIS. I only want points on the pixels with a '1' value, rather than have a point in EVERY cell (which apparently will take a day to process and will likely not load on my laptop if it completes). The pixel cell value should be either 1 or 0.
Is there a way to do this?

You need to set all raster values except those you want to vectorize to nodata.
For example using Reclassify by table.
I have a raster with many values, I want to create points only of the cells with value=2.
In reclassify by table, under Advanced settings set Use NoData when no range matches value = Yes.

My Reclassification table:

to set all pixels with value 2 to 1. All other values will be set to nodata because Use NoData when no range matches=Yes
Raster pixels to points will only create points of pixels with values other than nodata:


Thanks, I'm getting this error: "Invalid value for TABLE: list must contain a multiple of 3 elements (found 1)" what am I doing wrong?

Ah, I think I've fixed it. Thank god it's Friday! ‍♀️
